# Error calling HttpsURLConnection.getCipherSuite()

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm trying to run an example program that's failing in the call to `getCipherSuite()` with a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: connection not yet open exception`. The connection is open so not sure why this is happening. I'm using java version 1.6.0_18

Does anybody know why this is exception is raising?

Thanks.

```
package web.services.https;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SunClient {

  private static final String url_s = "https://java.sun.com:443";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SunClient().do_it();
  }

  private void do_it() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_s);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        System.out.println("\nConnected ...\n");

        dump_features(conn);
    }

    catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println("MalformedURLException exception: " + e);
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException exception: " + e);
    }

  }

  private void dump_features(HttpsURLConnection conn) {

    try {

        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();

        for(Certificate cert: certs) {
            print("\tCert. type: " + cert.getType());
            print("\tHash code: " + cert.hashCode());
            print("\tAlgorithm: " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
            print("\tFormat: " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
            print("");
        }

        print("Status code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        print("Cipher suite: " + conn.getCipherSuite());

    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception exception: " + e);
    }

  }

  private void print(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening for exactly the reason stated in the exception. You are calling it before the cnnextion is open. Solution: call it after, i.e. after calling getInputStream(), getResponseCode(), etc.

Comment: It is being called after getResponseCode(). I'm calling it directly after that very thing. The response code I'm getting back is 302.

Comment: I suggest you post more code. What you've posted so far doesn't show any of that.

Comment: The call to getResponseCode is included in the dump_features method (scroll down); It is wrapped in the call to the print method i.e. (print("Status code: " + conn.getResponseCode());) I then call the getCipherSuite in the next line after that in the same way.

Comment: I tried a different url (i.e. https://www.ibm.com:443) and it worked. It returned the same response code of 302 but the call to conn.getCipherSuite() worked. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: @Paul I just got the same issue when fetching an endpoint that returns no body (204). Testing your URL (https://java.sun.com:443) also returns no body, so I'm guessing that the common thread is the connection being in a weird state when the response is empty.